# AngularJS dependency-injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have say two modules:

1. `foo.a`
2. `foo.b`

and an application module:

```
  angular.module("foo", ["foo.a","foo.b"])
```

I have a service in module `foo.b` say:

```
  angular.module("foo.b", [])

  angular.module("foo.b").factory("helper",helperFn);
```

which I want to use in one of my controllers in `foo.a`.

What I have done is simple dependency injection:

```
 angular.module("foo.a", []);

 angular.module("foo.a")
        .controller("MyController",["helper",MyControllerFn]);
```

which is working.

My questions are

1. How am I getting the "helper" service from module `foo.b` even though it is     not declared as a dependency for module a?
2. Will it break at a later stage?
3. If it is correct, is this a good practice?

Comment: I am afraid you will get an error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: helperProvider <- helper`. Or put some JSFiddle to illustrate your issue.

Comment: the issue is that i am able to use a factory from other module without adding that module as a dependency   [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jAvtSPQWJjTPNd40YvVA?p=preview)

Answer (score 7):

Put the factory that you need access to in both modules in a third module.  Have your two original modules inject a dependency to the third module.

```
angular.module("foo", ["foo.a", "foo.b"]);

angular.module("foo.a", ["foo.c"])
  .controller("MyController", ["helper", MyControllerFn]);

angular.module("foo.b", ["foo.c"]);

angular.module("foo.c")
  .factory("helper", helperFn);
```